# Changing width of identify widget pop-up in Configurable Map Viewer?

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

How do I change the width of the identify tool pop-up in order to fit a table without having to scroll?

Image attached shows how it is at present. Note I want to change size of entire popup, not just the table.

[image: identify widget]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change that would be to set up a custom css file for the site.  within that file you would add:

```
    .esriPopup .sizer {
    width: 375px;
}
```